# How to bind DevExpress XtraReport by Query String

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms, devexpress, xtrareport

Can anybody tell me how I can bind a DevExpress XtraReport by Query String?

I want to show only the ID value of 8 in the report, I am using a store procedure to get data.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetLabReport", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        XtraReport1 Rept = new XtraReport1();
        string path = (Server.MapPath("App_Code/XtraReport1.cs"));
        DA.Fill(DT);
        connection.Close();
        if(DT.Rows.Count>0)
        {

        }
```

The above works fine with Crystal Reports but not with DevExpress XtraReports.

Comment: if you want to bind your xtrareport1 to the DA datatable, assign table to the report datasource "Rept.DataSource = DA"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create report parameters and then set the parameter value using the query string.

See the comments on below thread:
[Report Designer using SQL Server Stored Procedure as data source, generates .Net exception.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T121959/report-designer-using-sql-server-stored-procedure-as-data-source-generates-net-exception)

> Add a Report's Parameters and then map it to your query parameter. Then pass the value from Request.QueryString to the Parameter.Value property

**Example:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            XtraReport3 report = new XtraReport3();
            report.Parameters[0].Value = Request["MyParam"];
            ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = report;
        }
```

**References:**
[Passing querystring values to a report](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T178685/passing-querystring-values-to-a-report)
[How to use parameter from querystring to show report](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T126252/how-to-use-parameter-from-querystring-to-show-report)
[Parameters support thru URL QueryString in XtraReports?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T117980/parameters-support-thru-url-querystring-in-xtrareports)
[How to pass QueryString parameter into Report (master-detail) c#](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q384885/how-to-pass-querystring-parameter-into-report-master-detail-c)